# Circle, unit interval and unit square pairwise not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, universal-property

In my Topology exercise class I have the task to show that $S^1$, $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ are pairwise not homeomorphic, using the fact that $S^1$ fits into the following pushout square: $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD} \{0,1\} @>\operatorname{id}>> [0,1] \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\{\star\} @>>> S^1
\end{CD}
I think that I understand this fact (as the universal property indeed holds for $S^1$ by commutativity requirements).
But I am not really sure how to proceed now. The exercise feels as if I should assume two of the spaces to be homeomorphic and to derive a contradiction. But is it allowed to replace, say, $S^1$ by $[0,1]$ in the diagram to get a contradiction? Does this even make sense if we do not have an explicit homeomorphism?
Any hint is really appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, supposed $u:S^1\to X$ is a homeomorphism, you get another pushout square with $S^1$ replaced by $X$ when composing the right arrow by $u$ and the bottom arrow by $u^{-1}$. Actually, the same holds for any object of any diagram in any category: isomorphic objects can be so replaced by each other.

Comment: Berci's comment is right, but just wanted to point out for the OP that it can affect certain maps; in this case everything is going to turn out to be natural, but the uber-generality "any object of any diagram in any category can be replaced by an isomorphic object" is a bit iffy.  Here all the properties of your pushout square will go through, but for example if you had a diagram with the "id" going into the object you're going to change, then ofc you won't get an "id" any more - tho it will obviously be an iso, still, which is usually good enough for what you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks! They are very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is connected and $p \in X$ is such that $X\setminus \{p\}$ is disconnected, then $p$ is called a cut-point of $X$. Likewise, if $A \subseteq X$ is such that $X\setminus A$ is disconnected, $A$ is a cut-set of $X$. Easy fact: if $h: X \to Y$ is a homomorphism $A$ is a cut-set of $X$ iff $h[A]$ is a cut-set of $Y$.

So if $X \simeq Y$ they have the same numbers of cut-sets and (non-)cut-points. This is a rough but general tool to reason about certain connected spaces being homeomorphic or not:

- $[0,1]$ has $2$ non-cutpoints (the endpoints), all other points are cut-points.
- $\Bbb S^1$ has no cut-points but any subset of size $2$ is a cut-set.
- $[0,1]^2$ has no cut-points and no subset of size $2$ is a cut-set.

So for your three spaces such simple considerations suffice.

Comment: This is indeed very simple and nice! Thanks for the argument.